# How to load csv file to Oracle table in faster way using Python

Tags: python, oracle, csv, cx-oracle

I am researching over the internet how to load CSV file to Oracle DB table in a faster way

Below is the way I was loading the table which as 1000 records in file and got loaded within no time.

But if there are 50,000 records it takes approx. 5 minutes to load.

Is there any faster and efficient way to load csv file to Oracle table?

**My code :**

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

myquery='insert into TABLE (COLUMNNAME1,COLUMNNAME2,COLUMNNAME3,COLUMNNAME4,COLUMNNAME5,COLUMNNAME6) values (:1, :2, :3 ,:4,:5,:6)'
separator='|'

oracleConnection='user/password@hostIP/database'

def fileLoading(oracleconnection, file_name,myquery,separator):
    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(oracleConnection)
        print("Connection established")
        reader = csv.reader(open("demp.csv", "r"), header=None,delimiter=separator)
        columns = []
        for line in reader:
            columns.append(line)
            cur = con.cursor()
            for line in columns:
                print("Inserting record to table")
                insrt_stmt = myquery
                cur.execute(insrt_stmt, line)
                con.commit()
                cur.close()
                print("load completed")
    except Exception as er:
        print('ERRO:',er)
```

Comment: That rate corresponds to your 1000 records taking 6 seconds, which some might consider "no time".

Comment: As this is Oracle, I'd use **SQL Loader** which is really *fast*.

Comment: You could try cursor.executemany that could help in improving the speed and also try having one  commit statement.

Comment: just setup an external table https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

Comment: Remove the "print". Use `insrt_stmt = myquery` only once outside the loop. Use only one `commit` at the end. Open and close the cursor only once.

Comment: You open new cursor, do insert, commit and close cursor for each line. With this approach overhead is too high. You should open cursor only once before reading the file, read some amount of rows, do `cursor.executrmany` for them, then commit and retrieve the next portion of data.

Answer (score 3):

[Update: cx_Oracle was renamed to [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/). See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) - use this version instead of cx_Oracle. This answer has been updated to use python-oracledb.]

Use `executeMany()` as shown in the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database).  This is much faster than repeated calls to `execute()`:

```
import oracledb
import csv

. . .

# Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

# Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
batch_size = 10000

with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```

There is a runnable example in [samples/load_csv.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/load_csv.py).

Comment: Can you provide your input here : data is not getting loaded to table using execute many https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68607481/unable-to-load-data-from-file-to-table-using-execute-many-python  and improvements in code which will make my code work I followed the above execute many , but not loading to table

Comment: Start by reading the doc, making sure you have the correct `setinputsizes` values (for simple testing just delete that line), try with just a few rows of data, telling us whether you got an error etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with python but I would try like this:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(oracleConnection)
print("Connection established")
reader = csv.reader(open("demp.csv", "r"), header=None,delimiter=separator)
cur = con.cursor()
insrt_stmt = myquery

for line in reader:
   columns = []
   for line in columns:
       columns.append(line)
       cur.execute(insrt_stmt, line)
con.commit()
cur.close()
print("load completed")
```

Comment: Nope!  Use [`executeMany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) which is much faster than repeated called to `execute()`