# Unable to load data from file to Oracle table using executeMany()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am struggling with below code to twik where i am going wrong and why my table is not getting loaded with data

**My Oracle table structure :**

**Table name : test**

```
create table test
(
    id number,
    name varchar2(50 char),
    surname varchar2(50 char),
    age number,
    country varchar2(50 char)
)
```

I am not getting any error in log file and nor table loaded with data

I have 10,000 records in file and records are pipe separated : `'|'`

**My code:**

```
import logging
import cx_Oracle
import csv

insertQuery="insert into test (id,name,surname,age,country) values (:1, :2 , :3 , :4 , :5)"
invalue='line[0], line[1] , line[2] , line[3] , line[4]'
oracleconnection = 'user/password@hostIP/database'
my_separator='|'
file_name = demo_2021.csv

def loadtable(oracleconnection,my_query,file_name,my_separator):
    try:
        con=cx_Oracle.connect(oracleconnection)
        cur=con.cursor()

        # Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
        cur.setinputsizes(None, 25)

        # Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
        batch_size = 10000

        with open(file_name, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=my_separator,header=None)
            sql = insertQuery
            data = []
            for line in csv_reader:
                data.append((invalue))
                if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
                    cur.executemany(sql, data)
                    data = []
            if data:
                cur.executemany(sql, data)
            con.commit()
    except Exception as er:
        logging.error(f'{er}')
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `data.append((invalue))` with `data.append(line)`?

Comment: Correction, try with `data.append(tuple(line))`. It needs a list of tuples...

Comment: `data.append((invalue))` makes no sense, because for every line you append a tuple with the same content: exactly one string declared at the very beginning. But your query expects five bind variables for each line. If `line` is a tuple, then append it as is and then `executemany`. See [cx_Oracle: Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html)

Comment: @astentx can you tell how to modified above code so that it will load data to table

Comment: @astentx  : This should be dynamic : data.append((invalue))  not hard coded like you shared in above link

Comment: The statement in the linked article accepts external (relative to the statement) data and executes the statement for every row in the list passed to `executemany`. It doesn't matter how this list was obtained, so it is not static. You should use `data.append(line)`. You may also check the linked article for how to handle errors in batch.

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question you should fix the line `cur.setinputsizes(None, 25)`.  Start by deleting it (so cx_Oracle chooses sizes).  Then once you have the rest of the code working you can add a similar line back, with values for each of your columns, something like `cur.setinputsizes(None, 50, 50, None, 50)`  This line lets Oracle preallocate memory so it doesn't have to do a (slow) realloc.

Answer (score 2):

With this test data file:

```
1|Fred|Nurke|21|UK
2|Henry|Crun|21|UK
```

this code works:

```
import logging
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import sys
import os

if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")

insertQuery="insert into test (id,name,surname,age,country) values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5)"
oracleconnection = 'un/pw@localhost/orclpdb1'
my_separator='|'
file_name = 'demo_2021.csv'

try:
    con=cx_Oracle.connect(oracleconnection)
    cur=con.cursor()

    # Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
    cur.setinputsizes(None, 50, 50, None, 50)

    # Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
    batch_size = 10000

    with open(file_name, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=my_separator)
        data = []
        for line in csv_reader:
            data.append((line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4]))
            if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
                cur.executemany(sql, data)
                data = []
        if data:
            cur.executemany(insertQuery, data)
        con.commit()

        
except Exception as er:
    print(er)
```

In SQL*Plus afterwards:

```
  ID NAME  SURNAME AGE COUNTRY
---- ----- ------- --- -------
   1 Fred  Nurke    21 UK
   2 Henry Crun     21 UK
```